# Proof of an algebra (measure theory)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> Suppose $\mathcal{F}$ is a collection of subsets of $\Omega$ such that $\Omega\in\mathcal{F}$. Supose that whenever $A,B\in\mathcal{F} \implies A$\ $B\in\mathcal{F}$ Proof that $\mathcal{F}$ is an algebra.

$\mathcal{F}$ is called an algebra if:

i) $\Omega,\emptyset\in\mathcal{F}$

ii) $S\in\mathcal{F}\implies S^c\in\mathcal{F}$

iii) $S_1,...,S_n\in\mathcal{F}\implies\bigcup^n_{i=1} S_i\in\mathcal{F}$

I have difficulties proving:
$$S_1,...,S_n\in\mathcal{F}\implies\bigcup^n_{i=1} S_i\in\mathcal{F}$$ 
Let $A,B\in\mathcal{F}$, then $A^c,B^c\in\mathcal{F}$. It follows that $A^c$\ $B\in\mathcal{F}\Rightarrow A^c\cap B^c=(A\cup B)^c\in\mathcal{F}$. Then $(A\cup B)^c)^c=(A\cup B)\in\mathcal{F}$

This proves the statement for two arbitrary sets, but I am not sure that is sufficient for prooving any finite union of sets. Could anyone help me here?

Comment: Induction in the number of sets would do it.

Comment: Of course: Apply induction in $n$. For $n=2$ you gave a proof. Finish by induction.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I've never done induction with implications (only (in)equalities). Right now I have:$\bigcup_{i=1}^{n+1} s_i=s_{n+1}\cup[\bigcup_{i=1}^n s_i]=$. How can I apply the induction hypothesis that $s_1,…,s_{n}\in\mathcal{F}\implies[\bigcup_{i=1}^n s_i]\in\mathcal{F}$ ?

Comment: Never mind, got it!